# Constructors starting with the ~ in a class

Tags: c#, oop

In this example link ....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737565/2948523

I found some sections like,
~ImprovedClass()
~Inner()

Please help me out what are they ? why and how should I use them in code

```
            class Inner
            {
                public Inner(IntPtr unkOuter)
                {
                }

                ~Inner()
                {
                }
            }

        public class ImprovedClass 
        {
            // constructor
            public ImprovedClass()
            {
            }

            ~ImprovedClass()
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: they are called destructors, google it

Comment: Destructors, Search it or thorughly study OOPs

Comment: "why and how should I use them in code" short answer: almost never

Comment: I must have written about 5 finalizers/destructors in .NET code (not including demo code on "here is a finalizer"); in 4 of those 5 cases, it was temporary `#if DEBUG` code to try to figure out which objects weren't being disposed correctly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think you could shorten your answer even further by removing "almost". I can't remember ever using a class destructor in anything but C++.

Comment: @DavidArno They can be useful in some specialized scenarios. For example [debugging memory pools](http://ayende.com/blog/4827/answer-stopping-the-leaks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ mark is used for destructor not the constructor.

> When you are using unmanaged resources such as handles and database
>   connections, you should ensure that they are held for the minimum
>   amount of time, using the principle of acquire late and release early.
>   In C++ releasing the resources is typically done in the destructor,
>   which is deterministically run at the point where the object is
>   deleted. The .NET runtime, however, uses a garbage collector (GC) to
>   clean up and reclaim the memory used by objects that are no longer
>   reachable; as this runs on a periodic basis it means that the point at
>   which your object is cleaned up is nondeterministic. The consequence
>   of this is that destructors do not exist for managed objects as there
>   is no deterministic place to run them.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Destructor [Destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)

They are used to release resources that the object may still be holding onto even though it is no longer in use.

Comment: Please elaborate more, or leave a comment instead of answer

Comment: I did not down vote, but sometimes people look for verbose answers.

Comment: What more do you want said? Read the link if you don't know what a destructor is.

Answer (score 2):

Those are called destructors which are calling automatically at the end of your class instance life on instance. You can write code here to release some resources which have been used by your object. Here are some remarks about destructors:

1. Destructors cannot be defined in structs.
2. They are only used with classes.
3. A class can only have one destructor
4. Destructors cannot be inherited or overloaded.
5. Destructors cannot be called. They are invoked automatically.

Here is some guide
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/66x5fx1b.aspx